# recompute of the computed property

Tags: swift, swiftui, computed-properties, swift-data

Good day, please tell me, is it possible to somehow change the behavior of Computed Property?

What is happening here: we show a list of transactions that are dynamically grouped by dates

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct TransactionsList: View {
    
    @Query(sort: [
        SortDescriptor(\Transaction.dateTransaction, order: .reverse)
    ]) var transactions: [Transaction]
    
    var groupedTransactionByDate: [Date : [Transaction]] {
        print("Grouping transaction")
        return Dictionary(grouping: transactions, by: { $0.dateTransaction })
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(groupedTransactionByDate.keys.sorted(by: >), id: \.self) { date in
                    Section(header: Text(date, style: .date).font(.headline)) {
                        ForEach(groupedTransactionByDate[date]!) { transaction in
                            TransactionRow(transaction: transaction)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Here the log is printed several thousand times

> Here in such a code, if we have 5k transactions in the database, when obtaining the MAP value (27 line), we recalculate the value of the `groupedTransactionbyDate` variable and allot the memory of 2 GB, which is why oom Killer kills the application

I used to think that the calculated properties count and update only when changing variables that are involved in the calculation, and it turns out to be at every mention of this variable

#### Possible solutions to the problem

As if it begs to return the two values of Key and Value in the 25th line so that Value can no longer recalculate to each mention, but I did not find a way to do it

I can do when initializing the Fetchdescriptor and fill out the `groupedTransactionByDate` variable in advance, but then it will not be updated when data changes in the database in background

#### What did I try to do

I tried to make the simplest model with two fields and try to group it also, which excludes the change in this model from the outside, but this has led to the fact that for each receipt of the computed properties we recalculate

#### What behavior I need

1. When the screen is opened, once we take data from the database (when the data changes in the database, we will recalculate the entire screen)
2. Once a variable `groupedTransactionByDate` will be counted
3. Once we will draw the screen until it changes/add/delete at least one transaction in the database, after which 1, 2 and 3 points are again counted

Comment: Consider Switching to CoreData instead so you can use SectionedFetchedRequest

Comment: One thing to try, put the query in one view and the computed property and List code in a sub view

Comment: @JoakimDanielson this is a good idea, I will try to implement it and write in a comment, thanks

Comment: @loremipsum This is not quite a good output to rewrite the entire application from one database to another due to such a problem)

Comment: Having 5k transactions in memory will likely lead to a terrible UI experience especially on older phones. Like I said just consider… sometimes rewrites are worth it.

Comment: @loremipsum pagination is the next step in developing this screen, but it is already necessary to implement this with the help of a new database

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It helped, it does not look very beautiful, but it works. Thank you very much

Comment: NP just  suggestion SwiftData is just still very new and not the best tool for large data sets. Pagination/batch size is also included with CoreData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to store the grouped transactions in a local variable in `body`. This guarantees that the computation is done exactly once each time SwiftUI asks `TransactionsList` for its `body`.

```
struct TransactionsList: View {
    
    @Query(sort: [
        SortDescriptor(\Transaction.dateTransaction, order: .reverse)
    ]) var transactions: [Transaction]
    
    var body: some View {
        let groupedTransactionByDate = Dictionary(
            grouping: transactions,
            by: { $0.dateTransaction }
        )
    
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(groupedTransactionByDate.keys.sorted(by: >), id: \.self) { date in
                    Section(header: Text(date, style: .date).font(.headline)) {
                        ForEach(groupedTransactionByDate[date]!) { transaction in
                            TransactionRow(transaction: transaction)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It really works and looks quite neat, thank you very much